# cannot find symbol when casting an object to a subtype

Tags: java, constructor, casting

Trying to write a constructor that will make a new CastTest object from an Object IF it is an instance of CastTest, like so (x is an instance variable of CastTest):

```
public CastTest(Object theTestObj)  
    {
        if (theTestObj instanceof CastTest) {
            //this.x = theTestObj.x; // Error: cannot find symbol: variable x ???
            //this.x = (CastTest) theTestObj.x; // Error: cannot find symbol: variable x ???
            //this.x = theTestObj.getX(); // Error: cannot find symbol: method getX() ???
            //this.x = (CastTest) theTestObj.getX(); // Error: cannot find symbol: method getX() ??? 
        }
    }
```

Why can't it find the variable or the method? They are defined right in the same class definition.

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables are resolved on the declared type of the reference. `Object` does not have an `x` instance field. The proper cast is

```
((CastTest)theTestObj).x
// this whole expression is of type CastTest which seems to have a field x
```

What you have, this

```
(CastTest) theTestObj.x;
```

is equivalent to

```
(CastTest) (theTestObj.x)
```

which has the same issue explained previously as

```
theTestObj.x
```